# Keil uVision 5 - Debugger starts in Startup, not actual code. Cant debug code

Tags: assembly, arm, armv7

I have a basic test project, that I'm trying to debug in Keil.

I import the .s file, and set up the project for simulator debugging:

[image]

However, when I click "Debug", instead of debugging Division.s, it debugs Startup_ARMCM3.s

[image]

and no matter how much I press iterate, it never moves to Division.s to debug.

How can I debug specifically the file I made?

Comment: It starts debugging from the start. Your main() function should call some code in your Divisions.s, only then stepping will go into your code. If main() doesn't call you code, the debugger won't step in your code.

Comment: And how can I call it in assembly? This is meant as a hello world style program to start messing around in assembly, I really just want to be able to debug a basic .s program to see the results, not program a whole board before I know firmly how STR works.

Comment: Replace all instances of `SystemInit` in the code above with your routine name and it should be called after reset.

Answer (score -2):

This is due to in the "system_TM4c123.c" the following macro is set to 1:

```
#define CLOCK_SETUP 1
```

which leads to the execution of `SystemInit(void)` function first thing the debugger starts.

**Solution**: change

```
#define CLOCK_SETUP 1
```

to:

```
#define CLOCK_SETUP 0
```